# The "garden path" theory of ambiguity resolution. apply to the joke:

Tags: ambiguity

Does the "garden path" theory of ambiguity resolution apply to the joke:

A seal walked into a club...

Given that the listener probably is familiar with this type of joke:

A sandwich walks into a bar ….
A priest walks into a bar…
A string walks into a club…

then this theory might lead the them to choose

A seal walked into(entered) a club(drinking establishment).

If I am wrong what is another possible ambiguity resolution theory that explains the humor in the joke. I might suggest that "pragmatics" also explains the resolution process as the context is laid by the presence of similar style jokes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think jokes like this actually could be referred to as garden path sentences; as you said, the usual expectation for this joke template is that the subject entered a drinking establishment, while the actual meaning of this version of it is that the seal collided with a large, blunt, rounded weapon while walking. That said, this does rely on knowing what the usual template of "a/an X walked into a bar..." jokes is, which may discount it from the definition as that isn't strictly related to how one parses it.

Answer (score 2):

*Garden path* refers to phrasing that leads the reader to misparse a sentence.  It comes from the idiom "to lead someone down a garden path", meaning to mislead them.  A garden path is a pleasant venue, so it's easy to see why someone would take such a walk, not realizing that it takes them to an undesirable destination.

A *garden path* is syntactic.  For instance from the song (and the movie of the same name):

> Throw mama from the train a kiss

The initial parsing treats *mama* as the direct object of *throw* because the prepositional phrase follows *mama* directly.  The complement *a kiss* at the end of the sentence reveals that the reader has been misled and the meaning is

> Throw a kiss to mama from the train.

Notice that the ridiculous meaning of the first parsing does not rely on any lexical confusion, i.e., the words mean the same thing in both versions.

With

> a seal walked into a club

there are two meanings, but not two parsings.  Both are Subject-Verb-Prepositional phrase.  The difference in meaning relies on two meanings of club (a weapon and an entertainment venue) and two meaning of into (bump into and enter).

Comment: The old man the boat. The complex houses married soldiers and their families.

Comment: Hi John Clifford, so you believe that, because the ambiguity is semantic, not syntactic, it cannot be "garden path?" The word order in this care is not in question? Can you suggest another possibility?

Comment: It was deadrat who posted the answer, but he's edited to cover your query I believe. :)

Comment: apologies to you and deadrat.

Comment: @SimonG No offense taken as none was offered.  Did the answer make sense to you?

Comment: deadrat, many thanks. yes, it makes perfect sense. i wonder if you could offer a different ambiguity resolution process.

Comment: I think most people would just refer to a joke where the words have multiple meanings as a **pun**, Simon.

Comment: deadrat - with such a joke there tends to be a lag between the telling and the realization by the listener as to the "real" meaning. Would it be safe to say that the process which leads to the final epiphany is a case of "priming?" as in "club" primes both weapon and drinking place, "walks" primes both enter and collide?

Comment: @SimonG I should have been pinged by your comments, but I wasn't.  I'm not sure what you mean of a "different ambiguity resolution process."  As for *priming*, I'm not sure you can define that in a useful (i.e., operational) way.  I don't think anyone knows how the brain accesses its lexicon.